# How to keep track of database changes using phpmyadmin trigger and stored log into another table?

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

This is my trigger code.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `qty_chgs` AFTER UPDATE ON `cart`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF NEW.QUANTITY != OLD.QUANTITY THEN
    INSERT INTO logs (`action`,`product_id`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) VALUES (1,NEW.PRODUCT_ID,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
    END IF;
END
```

### Cart table

cart_id | product_id | qty | price |

### Users table

user_id | username | password |

### Order table

order_id | request_id | cart_id |

### Request table

request_id | cart_id |

Here comes my question. How can i do to keep track of which user is modify the cart table when the quantity changed?

Other than that, i have order and request interface, when user make changes for ordered item then order_id will be logged else request_id will be logged if user make changes for requested item. Is that possible to keep track of whether the user is made changes on order or request?

In brief, i want to log the product modified and which user modified it also get to know modified during ordered or made request.